# Javascript Uppercase first x characters if matching specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uppercase, capitalization

I'm trying to work out in javascript / jquery how to capitalise the first 3 characters of a string, if that string starts with one of several matches.

In php I can do:

```
$loc = (preg_match("/^(nww|nsw|esw|sew|wes)/i", $loc)) ? strtoupper( substr( $loc, 0, 3 ) ).substr( $loc, 3 ) : ucfirst($loc);
```

Which would change `nsw48751` to `NSW48751`, but change newlease to Newlease.

How can I do this in javascript or jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, but if the rest of the string bar the first 3 characters are numerical, then you can just call `toUpperCase()` and be done.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to alternate between matching any of those 3 letters, and if none of those are found, match the first letter in the string. Then, use a replacer function to capitalize the match:

```js
const change = str => str.replace(/^(?:nww|nsw|esw|sew|wes|[a-z])/i, match => match.toUpperCase());
console.log(change('nsw48751'));
console.log(change('newlease'));
```

Comment: Thanks this is great :)

Answer (score 1):

Can use [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if the regular expression satisfies your condition and btw the solution by CertainPerformance is awesome!

```js
var string1 = 'nsw48751';
var string2 = 'newLetter';


function foo (str) {
  r = /^(nww|nsw|esw|sew|wes)/i
  if (r.test(str)) {
    return str.substring(0,3).toUpperCase() + str.substring(3)
  }
  return str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
}

console.log(foo(string1));
console.log(foo(string2));
```